# Save a map with Lidar

Tags: navigation, rviz, gmapping, base-laser, hokuyo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I follow this tutorial for save a map : http://wiki.ros.org/slam_gmapping/Tutorials/MappingFromLoggedData#record
I create my own bag, and i see on rviz the Lidar data.
But when I launch the command " rosrun gmapping slam_gmapping scan:=base_scan " there are nothing on my terminal. is normal?
After that, I wrote "rosbag play --clock nameofmybag.bag" --->>>  it's done, and " rosrun map_server map_saver". On my terminal, there are writing "waiting for de map" but nothing after that. What's the problem?

(When i launch the last command, in my another terminal " rosrun gmapping .." they are write : TF_OLD_DATA ignoring data from the past for frame base_footprint at time .... )

Thanks for your Help

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/172636/save-a-map-with-lidar/) by [guigui](https://answers.ros.org/users/16871/guigui/) on ROS Answers with karma: 33 on 2014-06-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

TF_OLD_DATA probably means that you have not set sim time to true. When playing back bagfiles, you have to use sim time so that the clock published by rosbag will be used by nodes that need to interact with time:

```
rosparam set use_sim_time true
```

This should be run after starting your roscore, but BEFORE starting gmapping or rosbag

---

Originally posted by [fergs](https://answers.ros.org/users/84/fergs/) with karma: 13902 on 2014-06-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0